# ASP.NET Core HttpClient request returns 200 when webapi returns 406

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to do simple login with httpclient post request but the client side only returns 200 instead of anything else with bad credentials. Below are my code

#### Consumer Side

```
[HttpPost("/login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUser loginUser)
{
    string redirectPage = "LoginPage";
    // string result = "";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/webapi");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("login", loginUser);
       
        Console.WriteLine(response);

        if (response.ReasonPhrase == "OK")
        {
            redirectPage = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bad Login");
            redirectPage = "LoginPage";
        }

    }
}
```

#### API Side

```
[HttpPost]
public string Login(object data)
{
    HttpResponseMessage loginResponse;
    UserLogin credentials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserLogin>(data.ToString());
    
    Console.WriteLine(credentials.Username + " " + credentials.Password);
    User dbUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Username == credentials.Username);
    User dbUserPw = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Password == credentials.Password);


    if (dbUser != null && dbUserPw != null){
        loginResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else{
        loginResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(loginResponse);
    
    return loginResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

and when I try to log in with incorrect credentials

the API side returns

```
StatusCode: 406, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Acceptable', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
}
```

but the client side returns

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Tue, 08 Jun 2021 23:12:48 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
```

would anyone know what the problem would be?

Comment: `would anyone know what the problem would be?` You aren't returning a 406 from `Login`. The software isn't magic, it doesn't know you want to do that. You need to actually do it.

Comment: I am also not convinced you are returning a 406. I think you are returning a 300 _with the value 406 in the payload._

Comment: Both the above Login code are part of the same project? same controller? Even when API is returning 406, the first login action returns 200 status only.... you need to change the status code of response if the API returns 406.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I found your response type is string and you just return a string response to the client side.

This is the reason why you always get 200 status codes.

If you want to return the 406 status codes, I suggest you could use `ContentResult` instead of `IActionResult`.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(object data)
{
    return new ContentResult() { Content = "aaa", StatusCode = (int?)HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable };

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by changing PostJsonAsync method to

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("login", loginUser).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```